# 2 leds in series

Tags: electronics

Why on the first picture LEDs are blinking, but on the second they're not?

[image]

[image]

Comment: At the very least a circuit diagram is required, there's very little information to go on here

Comment: I assume voltage across each led in series will be 3.3V/2=1.65V possibly too low to drive the led. Unless one led is the wrong way round.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using a Raspberry Pi. It has an output voltage of about 3.3 volts. A 5mm LED (which you show) with a green lens has a typical forward voltage of 2.0V. Your problem (2+2=4) - 3.3 = 0.7 Volts. You do not have enough voltage to drive two LEDs in series, and doing them in parallel without using current limiting resistors will damage your Pi. Place them in parallel with a 470 Ohm resistor in series with each of them. They will work fine if the port is OK.